# Using Yarn 2 (Berry) for packaging application in a Docker image

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I'm migrating a VueJS application from "classic" Yarn 1.x to Yarn 2. Following the [install documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install) is straightforward and works without problems.

The tricky part comes when packaging the application in a Docker image.

**Current Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . ./

RUN yarn build --modern \
    && find dist -type f -exec gzip -k "{}" \;

FROM nginx:mainline-alpine as production-stage

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

HEALTHCHECK CMD curl -f http://localhost || exit 1

COPY docker/entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

COPY docker/app.nginx /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Maybe I looked in the wrong places but I couldn't find any information how a [Yarn 2 Zero-Install setup](https://yarnpkg.com/features/zero-installs) would look like for a Docker image.

Do you have any recommendation on how to use the Yarn 2 approach in a `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 12):

@Ethan's answer makes sense, and it *should* work. But for me I was getting this strange error during a build:

```sh
 > [ 7/10] RUN yarn --version:                                                                                                               
#11 1.430 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905                                                                                                 
#11 1.430   throw err;                                                                                                                       
#11 1.430   ^                                                                                                                                
#11 1.430                                                                                                                                    
#11 1.430 Error: Cannot find module '/base/.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs'
#11 1.430     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
#11 1.430     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
#11 1.430     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
#11 1.430     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
#11 1.430   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
#11 1.430   requireStack: []
#11 1.430 }
```

Even though I *definitely* copied `.yarn` to the image, how well.

I had to actually install yarn v2 within the build:

```js
FROM node:14.17.1 as build

WORKDIR /base
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn set version berry

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

**UPDATE**

Turns out Docker doesn't copy entire directories the way I thought it did.

I had to add an explict `COPY` for the `.yarn`:

```
COPY .yarn ./.yarn
```

Solved it for me.

Comment: thanks for the `COPY .yarn ./.yarn` hint, that was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Due to a weird catch-22 with yarn 2's package install process, I've found this to be the most effective method of installing yarn@berry with docker. There's likely a better method of doing it, but I'm not aware of one.

```
FROM node:latest as build
WORKDIR /app

# copy only the package.json file so yarn set version can
# correctly download its modules for berry without overwriting
# the existing yarnrc and cache files. If the rc is added now,
# yarn will attempt to use the berry module without it being
# installed.
COPY package.json .
RUN yarn set version berry

# and _now_ pull in the rest of the build files overriding
# the rc generated by setting the yarn version
COPY yarn.lock .yarn .yarnrc.yml ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .

# continue with your build process
```

***However***, I will note that yarn is intended to run from the local `.yarn/releases` folder, so the best method may simply be to install yarn2 in local and [add it to the repo as yarn recommends](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#which-files-should-be-gitignored). Then as a preliminary step with pulling in the `package.json` file, pull the necessary `.yarn` files with it as shown above. This *should* work under most circumstances, however it gave me difficulty sometimes, hence the above example.

```
FROM node:latest as build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy in the package file as well as other yarn
# dependencies in the local directory, assuming the
# yarn berry release module is inside .yarn/releases
# already
COPY package.json yarn.lock .yarn .yarnrc.yml ./

RUN yarn install
COPY . .

# continue with your build process
```